# How to get base address of struct proc_dir_entry

Tags: struct, linux-kernel

Is there any struct that one of its fields contain a pointer to `proc_dir_entry`? and such a pointer to `proc_inode` struct?
For example field `files` or `mm` of `task_struct` points to `files_struct` and `mm_struct`.

Comment: This is (potentially) highly dependent on kernel version. The best way to find out is to download the source of the kernel (or find an online LXR) and look yourself. You can grep for 'struct proc_dir_entry' and look through the results.

Comment: @ Dan Fego:I've done so in kernel 3.10 both `proc_inode` struct and `proc_dir_entry` struct are defined here: `Linux/fs/proc/internal.h`. But this couldn't help me to find any pointer to base address of these structs!

Comment: @DanFego How to include 'fs/proc/internal.h' in my kernel module source file?